# Design form with ComboTree

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My exercise is design form like WinRar, but I have a problem with ComboTree (I don't know how call it). I can't design it. Can you give me an example? And how can I use it? Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you about Treeview
Because WinRar uses that format.

If yes then please visit the [Tutorial for TreeView](http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview)
Or even you can visit [Another Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/TreeviewBasics04152007195731PM/TreeviewBasics.aspx)

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. But Combotree like a treeview in combobox..